# Problem with copying a vector of pointers of inherited classes

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, vector

I have two classes, one inherits the other:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    int a;
};

class B : public A
{
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* first;
    first->a = 5;
    std::vector<B*> second;
    second.push_back( first ); // the error appears at this line
}
```

When I try to `push_back()` an element of type `A*` to the array of elements of type `B*`, the following error appears:

```
 no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=B *, _Alloc=std::allocator<B *>]" matches the argument list
  argument types are: (A *)
  object type is: std::vector<B *, std::allocator<B *>>
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: While `B` is-an `A` (because of the inheritance) the opposite isn't true. Inheritance is a one-way relationship.

Comment: A `std::vector<B *>`, by definition, only contains elements that are of type `B *`.   A variable (or element) of type `B *` can only point to an object that is either a `B` or of a type derived from `B`.   An `A` is neither a `B` nor is it of a type derived from `B`  (since `B` is derived from `A`, not the reverse).       Without knowing why you think that an `A*` can be stored in a `std::vector<B *>`, it's impossible to offer a solution on how to "fix it".

Comment: Also the first two lines of your main contain an error. You didn't create an A yet; only a pointer to A. Therefore, the assignment in the second line, will assign to some random probably unallocated memory address. The first line should be something like `A* first = new A();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.

B is an A but not the reverse.

So it would have worked only if A inherited from B.

Answer (score 1):

child class can be interpret as father class's pointer, reverse not work.

corret one may be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    int a;
};

class B : public A
{
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B* first;
    first->a = 5;
    std::vector<A*> second;
    second.push_back( first ); 
}
```